# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when installing chromeless nodejs on Centos

Tags: npm, centos, chromeless

I'm trying to install a node js package on my server with CentOS 6:

```
npm install chromeless
```

but the installation fails with this message:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:945:3
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you install 'npm install npm -g' ? Possibly issue with npm version